# sum up price upgrade vice versa in linear script (ajax php script)

Tags: php

various button fire the ajax Script below

```
Buttongroup1 (is typeNumber = 0): one(is typeElement = 0) two(is typeElement = 1)
Buttongroup2 (is typeNumber = 1): tree(is typeElement = 0) four(is typeElement = 1)
Buttongroup2 (is typeNumber = 2): five(is typeElement = 0) six(is typeElement = 1)
```

each button has a upgrade value f. e. 0 or 20 or 90

if I click the buttons from top to bottom it works fine except with the last buttongroup
when the buttons are clicked vice versa I also get false prices

So my question is: how to ensure that the script accepts clicking vice versa and for the last buttons?

I hope you can get my problem. Here is the part of the script:

```
<?php

$i = 0;

        $this -> newPrice = $this -> getBasePrice($post); //sets basprice f. e. 20

        $productDataArr = Array();

while($config = $result_eigenschaften_row->fetch_assoc()): //loops thrue buttongroups

           $config_temp = explode("\n", $config['eigenschaften']);

           if($i == $this -> typeNumber) {

               $productDataArr[$i] = explode(',', $config_temp[$this->typeElement]); //gives a upgrade value f. e. 0 or 20 or 90 called as $productDataArr[$i][2] below

           }


                    $this -> newScalePrice = $this -> newPrice;

                 

                    if(!empty($productDataArr[$i])) {

                        $this -> faktor = (((trim($productDataArr[$i][2]) * 100) / $this->newScalePrice) / 100) + 1;

                    }

                        $this->newPrice = $this->newPrice * $this->faktor;

                        

    endwhile;
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? Where are you stuck exactly? "I want" isn't a problem. It's not even a question. Stackoverflow is not a free write-my-code service. You are expected to show some effort to research and implement it yourself, and then ask us when you have an actual issue in your code. See also [ask].

Comment: Also IMO the situation is a bit unclear. It would help a lot to have some sample data to work with, and expected result, alongside the code you've written in order to try and implement your new requirement, and the full description of the exact problem you're facing in that code.

Comment: P.S. You have asked a lot of questions which have answers given, but not once have you ever accepted an answer. You should mark the most useful answer as accepted and also consider upvoting it. If you don't bother to give credit for solutions, why should anyone consider spending time to help you?